# Want to do coreference resolution. Can't install neuralcoref, allennlp and required version of spacy

Tags: pytorch, nlp, allennlp, coreference-resolution

I'm trying to implement coreference resolution but everytime I end up on build errors. I'm doing it on google colab. Any suggestion for this or any other tools?

PyTorch version: `2.0.1+cu117`

Code:

```
!pip install spacy~=3.3.0
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
!pip install neuralcoref --no-binary neuralcoref
!pip install allennlp
!pip install allennlp-models
```

Error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: neuralcoref
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for neuralcoref (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for neuralcoref
  Running setup.py clean for neuralcoref
Failed to build neuralcoref
ERROR: Could not build wheels for neuralcoref, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Want to use neuralcoref or allennlp models to implement coreference resolution. Using allennlp predictor. And facing almost same error while installing the spacy==2.1.0 that everyone is suggesting to use.

Error:

```
ConfigValidationError: 

Config validation error

tagger -> label_smoothing   extra fields not permitted

{'nlp': <spacy.lang.en.English object at 0x7d2a6c23bdc0>, 'name': 'tagger', 'label_smoothing': 0.0, 'model': {'@architectures': 'spacy.Tagger.v2', 'nO': None, 'normalize': False, 'tok2vec': {'@architectures': 'spacy.Tok2VecListener.v1', 'width': 96, 'upstream': 'tok2vec'}}, 'neg_prefix': '!', 'overwrite': False, 'scorer': {'@scorers': 'spacy.tagger_scorer.v1'}, '@factories': 'tagger'}
```

want to resolve above error.